# Correct way of controlling layout for specific elements?

Tags: html, css

I am designing a particular form that will have a fieldset on the left that is a tall as the three fieldsets on the right.

I created 3 jsfiddles with different approaches:

Hacked with `<br>`: http://jsfiddle.net/pdgreen/GjdRj/

CSS Sibling Selector : http://jsfiddle.net/pdgreen/GjdRj/1/

IDs: http://jsfiddle.net/pdgreen/GjdRj/3/

The `<br>` solution is to act as a strawman.  It isn't to be taken seriously.  I like the CSS sibling selector solution because it doesn't need anything special in the HTML, but it very quickly gets out of control in terms of complexity.  Is using IDs the correct way?  I guess it is the most straight forward, but it just doesn't feel right.  Is there a better way?

Comment: Yeah I mean there are a million ways to go about this. Since you're setting a fixed height on all of your items, My immediate thought is to do two containers and on the item on the left just make the stuff the full width, display:inline-block. But you're really scatterbrained with the question.

Comment: Well, I would rather not set all of the heights individually.  Is there a way I could make both left and right sides match heights without specifying each height?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use `nth-child(n)`? [My fork of your jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TCLaW/1/)

The basic idea is:

```
.container > fieldset.fsGroup:first-child {
height:20em;
}

.container > fieldset.fsGroup:nth-child(2) {
    height:5em;
}
...
```